# Buffering video

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vimeo, capacitor

Stack:
"@ionic/vue": "^6.0.0",
"vue": "^3.2.21",
"@capacitor/cli": "3.3.4",

PROBLEM:

IOS: the video is not buffered. the user has to wait until the entire video is downloaded before playing it. the video is saved in vimeo platform.

ANDROID: this problem does not exist here

CODE:

```
<video controls>
    <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/progressive_redirect/playback/111/rendition/1080p/file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

expected solution:

I would need to buffer this video. to start immediately after opening and loading the video part

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/731378604?h=555b720291" width="640" 
height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p><a href="https://vimeo.com/731378604">ADIDAS FT. RICK &amp; MORTY - X 
SPEEDPORTAL</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/user30235767">Elise 
Hagedoorn</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```